# Searching for User in Powershell. Allow Choice for Duplicate User

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wrote a PowerShell script that searches for a user based on given input and then removes said user from all groups (except for Domain Users). However, while you can't have a user with the same name in an OU group, you can have a user with the same name in a different OU group in the organization. Would it be possible to search for a user (John Smith), and allow one to select which user to remove from all groups if a duplicate user is returned? Here is my script so far. It works, but this is the functionality I would like to add.

```
#Requires -Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Disable-ADUser{
    $msg = "Do you want to remove a user from all Security groups? [Y/N]"

    do { 
        $response = Read-Host -Prompt $msg

        if ($response -eq "y") { # Beginning of if statment

            #Asks user via a text prompt to ender the firstname and lastname of the end user to remove
            $firstName = Read-Host "Please provide the First name of the User"
            $lastName = Read-Host "Please provide the Last name of the User"

            #The user's samaccoutname is found by searching exactly for the user's first name and lastname given in the above prompts
            $samName = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$firstName' -and Surname -eq '$lastName'"| Select-Object -ExpandProperty "SamAccountName"

            #All of the user's groups are queried based on their sam name
            $listGroups = Get-ADUser -Identity $samName -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf

            #All of the user's groups are placed in an array
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$groupsArray = @($listGroups)

            #Every group in the groupsArray is cycled through
                foreach ($group in $groupsArray) {

                    #A text output is displayed before the user is removed from each group listed in the above array
                    #Once all groups have been cycled through, the for loop stops looping
                    
                    Write-Host "Removing $samName " -f green -NoNewline
                    Write-Host  "from $group" -f red 
                    $OutputLine="Removing $samName from $group"
                    
                    Out-File -FilePath remove_user_groups.log -InputObject $OutputLine -Append
                    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $samName 
                    }
        } # End of if statement
      

    } until ($response -eq "n")
}

Disable-ADUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Out-GridView. It allows me to select user(s) with mouse, or to select no one. See `-OutputMode`  parameter.

```
<# Example part #>
$data = @'
[    
    {displayName: "Don Pedro Fizikello", employeeNumber: "Emp001", phone: "+888888888" },
    {displayName: "Don Pedro Gonzalez", employeeNumber: "Emp002", phone: "+77777777777" },
    {displayName: "Natalia Marisa Oreiro", employeeNumber: "Emp456", phone: "+987654321" },
    {displayName: "Juan Carlos Rodrigez", employeeNumber: "Emp123", phone: "+1234567890"}
]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
$userList = @($data | Where-Object { $_.displayName -like 'Don*' })


#Real-world case from Active Directory: $userList = @( Get-ADUser -Filter "(displayName -like 'Don*')" -Properties @('displayName', 'phone') )

<# /Example part #>

$user = $null
if ($userList.Count -eq 1) {
    $user = $userList[0] # // The only entry 
} elseif ($userList.Count -gt 1) {
    $user = $userList | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title 'Select User you want co tall to or press cancel'
}

if ($null -eq $user) {
    # // There is no users found or selected by human
    Write-Host "Nothing to do" -f Yellow
} else {
    # // Work with User
    Write-Host "Call $($user.displayName) : $($user.phone)" -f Green
}
```

---

The `negative` option is that Out-GridView can not hide parameters that it will display. There are some workarounds depending on task. Example: I show only DisplayName and some ID in Out-GridView (no `phone` property), but I use returned ID to take full user (with `phone`) from cache I've created before.

This allows me not to break the original object ( if it's from Get-ADUser, it contains tons of human-useless data like SID, GUID, ObjectClass, ObjectCategory, etc. )

```
<# Example part #>
Same as previous
<# /Example part #>

$user = $null
$userCacheOriginal = @{}
$userCacheCut = @{}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $userList.Count; $i++)
{
    # !! Here I assign some entryUniqueId to two collections - 
    # - userCacheOriginal - Original user object with Phone field ( and others )
    # - userCacheCut - Transformed objects that contains only ID and info I want to show in Out-GridView
    $entryUniqueId = "Idx$($i)"
    $userCacheOriginal[$entryUniqueId] = $userList[$i]
    $userCacheCut[$entryUniqueId] = [PSCustomObject]@{ID = $entryUniqueId; displayName = $userList[$i].DisplayName;}
}

if ($userList.Count -eq 1) {
    $user = $userList[0] # // The only entry 
} elseif ($userList.Count -gt 1) {
    $userChoice = $userCacheCut.Values | <# Set order of columns this way#> Select @('ID', 'DisplayName') | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title 'Select User or press cancel'

    if (($null -ne $userChoice.ID) -and ($userCacheOriginal.ContainsKey($userChoice.ID))) # Check if returned value contains ID, 
    { # And select original user object from userCacheOriginal
        $user = $userCacheOriginal[$userChoice.ID]
    }
}

if ($null -eq $user) {
    # // There is no users found or selected by human
    Write-Host "Nothing to do" -f Yellow
} else {
    # // Work with User
    Write-Host "Call $($user.displayName) : $($user.phone)" -f Green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it console based, you can add a `while` loop that requires further input from the user.

```
#The user's samaccoutname is found by searching exactly for the user's first name and lastname given in the above prompts
$samName = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$firstName' -and Surname -eq '$lastName'"|
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty "SamAccountName"
if ($samname.count -gt 1) {
    $newsamname = $null
    while ($newsamname -notin $samname) {
        $newsamname = Read-Host "Multiple names were found:`n$($samname -join ""`n"")`nPlease type the SamAccountName of the target user"
    }
    $samname = $newsamname
}
```

The idea is if multiple user objects are found, then `$samname` will initially be a collection of count greater than one. Here the executor will be required to enter a valid `SamAccountName` value from the presented list. Otherwise, the loop will go on forever until the program is manually halted. You could build in a counter to automatically exit the program after a certain number of retries or exit when no value is entered. You could implement a menu system where a number can be entered, which corresponds to the index of the list.